# Configuring the keystore in axis2.xml

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, axis

I am trying publish axis2(axis2-1.6.2) web service over https for that am trying to configure keystore details in my axis2.xml as below,

```
<transportReceiver name="https"
    class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">9002</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
        <KeyStore>
            <Location>D:/Keys/server.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>western</Password>
            <KeyPassword>western</KeyPassword>
        </KeyStore>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
        <TrustStore>
            <Location>D:/Keys/server.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>western</Password>
        </TrustStore>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

The above configuration doesn't work

If i use HttpCoreNIOSSLListener instead of AxisServletListener, am getting the below error messages

```
12:36:03,452 ERROR [ListenerManager] Couldn't initialize the httpstransport listener
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener.getSSLContext(HttpCoreNIOSSLListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener.init(HttpCoreNIOListener.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager.init(ListenerManager.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initTransports(AxisServlet.java:503)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:458)
        at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)


        12:36:03,492 INFO  [HttpCoreNIOListener] HTTP Listener starting on port : 9002
12:36:03,582 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSL context may not be null
12:36:03,583 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.nhttp.SSLServerIOEventDispatch.<init>(SSLServerIOEventDispatch.java:56)
12:36:03,586 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener.getEventDispatch(HttpCoreNIOSSLListener.java:57)
12:36:04,038 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener.startServerEngine(HttpCoreNIOListener.java:85)
```

Any input is welcome!

Comment: Please state what doesn't work.  If you get an error, please share the error message.

Comment: @AndyJoiner: I am using jboss application server, I didnt get any error message on the server log and also didnt able to connect the url saying unable to connect